# Allowing only different 'any' types in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Say we have a function with signature

```
foo :: a -> b -> Int
```

Is it possible to enforce a constraint ensuring that **a** and **b** are different? That is

```
foo :: Int -> String -> Int -- ok
foo :: Int -> Int    -> Int -- not ok
```

The purpose of this question is to learn more about Haskell and perhaps solve a design issue I'm facing. My particular case does not make sense if a == b, so I'd like to disallow that at the compiler level. I probably could make this issue go away with a different design altogether but that's besides the point now - the Pandoras box has been opened and I'd like to learn if an equality constraint on the type level is possible.

Comment: Why do you want to put such a constraint? What would be the intended applications? Maybe with closed type families one could implement it as `type Family D a b :: Constraint where D t t = Impossible t ; D t t' = ()`. Still... why?

Comment: Is that because you want to have two different behaviors, depending on whether types a and b are distinct or not ?

Comment: Haskell doesn't have a notion of inequality at the type level like it does for equality (`~`). You *can* test [`(Data.Type.Equality.==)`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/Data-Type-Equality.html#t:-61--61-) against `False`: `foo :: (a == b) ~ False => a -> b -> Int` but I don't see the purpose here.

Comment: It can be useful for overlapping type families (described in [Handling Recursion in Generic ProgrammingUsing Closed Type Families](http://staff.mmcs.sfedu.ru/~ulysses/Papers/2018-TFP-dgp-recursion.pdf)): `type DecideEq :: Bool -> k -> k -> Constraint; class bool ~ (a == b) => DecideEq bool a b where decideEq :: Maybe (a :~: b)`

Comment: I've provided additional information in the main question.

Comment: Thanks for adding additional information, it does not describe why `a == b` doesn't make sense. If you could give a usecase I am sure you would get clearer answers.

Comment: @PetrasPurlys, if `foo :: Int -> Int -> Int` doesn't make sense, what sense would `foo :: Int -> SomeType -> Int` make for `newtype SomeType = SomeType Int`? It would be allowed by the logic you want, but it would, after all, still hide a `foo :: Int -> Int -> Int`.

Comment: @Enlico Int, as a second parameter, would not have a single use case, so we would not need to have SomeType containing an Int.

Comment: @PetrasPurlys, I'm not saying it would. I'm just saying that one could "circumvent" your `-- not ok` by wrapping `Int` in a `newtype`.

Comment: @Iceland_jack It's not straightforward to give a thorough explanation why in my case a -> b -> c would only make sense when a /= b. Also, this question is more about understanding what is allowed in GHC as I've arrived at this situation probably because of a design decision that if done in an another way, would probably resolve the issue altogether.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like this?

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds #-}
module TyEq where

import Data.Type.Equality (type (==))
import GHC.TypeLits
import Data.Kind (Constraint)

class ((a == b) ~ eq) => Foo a b eq where
  foo :: a -> b -> Int

instance (TypeError ('Text "NAUGHTY!"), (a == b) ~ True) => Foo a b 'True where
  foo _ _ = error "The types have failed us!"

instance (a == b) ~ False => Foo a b 'False where
  foo _ _ = 42

--_ = foo True True -- NAUGHTY!
_ = foo () True
_ = foo True (42 :: Int)
```

Notice how the `eq` index is needed in the Foo type class, or we're getting 'duplicate instance' errors despite differing instance contexts (only heads are taken into account).

We can streamline that a bit using purpose-specific type family:

```hs
type family Check a b :: Constraint where
  Check a a = TypeError ('Text "VERY NAUGHTY!")
  Check a b = ()

foo' :: Check a b => a -> b -> Int
foo' _ _ = 42

--_ = foo' True True -- VERY NAUGHTY!
_ = foo' () True
_ = foo' True (42 :: Int)
```

I'm pretty sure I've learnt that all from Sandy Maguire's 'Thinking with Types', which I sincerely recommend to everyone interested :)

Comment: I just posted another flavor of this as my answer. No `error` calls, and a pattern for dispatch that's a bit more conventional.

Comment: @dfeuer I have to say I find the `foo' :: Check a b => a -> b -> Int` proposed in this answer more conventional than the twisty sequence of classes in your answer. (And there's no `error` in the implementation of `foo'`.)

Answer (score 8):

The type `a :~: b -> Void` is inhabited (by a total function) exactly when `a` and `b` are different, so one lightweight way would be to take one as an argument. You can then ask the compiler to check whether callers supply a total argument with `-Wincomplete-patterns`. A complete example might look like this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE EmptyCase #-}
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}

import Data.Void
import Data.Type.Equality

foo :: (a :~: b -> Void) -> a -> b -> Int
foo _ _ _ = 0

fooUseGood :: Int
fooUseGood = foo (\case) True () -- accepted, no warning

fooUseBad :: Int
fooUseBad = foo (\case) () () -- warning: Patterns not matched: Refl
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's a riff on Artur's version. It uses machinery developed for the `trivial-constraints` package.

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, KindSignatures, MultiParamTypeClasses, FlexibleInstances, FlexibleContexts, AllowAmbiguousTypes, TypeApplications, ScopedTypeVariables, ExplicitNamespaces, TypeOperators, UndecidableSuperClasses, UndecidableInstances #-}


import Data.Type.Equality (type (==))
import GHC.TypeLits
import GHC.Exts (Any)

-- The Any constraint prevents malicious/ignorant
-- instantiation with no = undefined. The only
-- way to produce an instance of this class is in a local context
-- using something deeply unsafe like unsafeCoerce, magicDict, or unsafePerformIO.
class Any => Bottom where
  no :: a

-- Why not just put the `no` method in this class?
-- Because then `no` will need to be applied to the type argument `e`, which is
-- very annoying and unnecessary.
class (TypeError e, Bottom) => Oops e

class Foo a b (eq :: Bool) where
  foo' :: a -> b -> Int

foo :: forall a b. Foo a b (a == b) => a -> b -> Int
foo = foo' @a @b @(a == b)

instance Oops ('Text "NAUGHTY!") => Foo a b 'True where
  foo' = no

instance Foo a b 'False where
  foo' _ _ = 42
```